# ¿Es posible justificar a la derecha la segunda parte de una cadena en Java o en Android?

Tags: java, android, string, formato

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de justificar la segunda parte de esta cadena en Java o en Android **manteniendo la cadena en la misma línea**:

```
Responsorio Ct 2, 3; Sal 15, 11
```

Lo que quiero lograr sería algo así, asumiendo que `|` representaría los extremos (margen derecho e izquierdo, por ejemplo en la pantalla de un dispositivo móvil):

```
|Responsorio               Ct 2, 3; Sal 15, 11|
```

Aquí la primera parte es fija (siempre será `Responsorio`) pero la segunda parte (`Ct 2, 3; Sal 15, 11`) **es dinámica**. Lo que quiero es que la segunda parte sea empujada hacia el margen derecho. Estuve mirando `String.format()` pero no encuentro la forma de hacer lo que quiero, todos los ejemplos son para rellenar/justificar cadenas, pero no para empujar parte de una cadena hacia un margen.

El problema aquí, según creo, es que habría que buscar la forma de saber la dimensión de que se dispone para agregar espacios en blanco sobrantes entre ambas cadenas. Quizá esto no sea posible en Java directamente y haya que recurrir a otras cosas ¿? De todos modos abro la pregunta, por si alguien supiera algún modo de hacer esto en Java.

La finalidad es presentar la cadena en una aplicación Android.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando, siguiendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612380/5587982):

```
public SpannableStringBuilder getHeader() {
    SpannableStringBuilder sb=new SpannableStringBuilder();
    String text="Responsorio";
    final String resultText = text + "\n\n" + getRef();
    final SpannableString styledResultText = new SpannableString(resultText);
    styledResultText.setSpan(
            new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE),
            text.length() + 2,
            text.length() + 2 + getRef().length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    );
    sb.append(styledResultText);
    sb.append(LS2);
    return sb;
}
```

Y funciona **parcialmente**. Sólo que me muestra el texto de la derecha en la siguiente línea:

```
|Responsorio                                  |
|                          Ct 2, 3; Sal 15, 11|
```

Yo quiero mostrarlo **en la misma línea**, pero si quito los saltos aquí:

```
    final String resultText = text + " " + getRef();
```

El código falla con el error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (13 ... 32) ends beyond
> length 31

Comment: Es modo consola?

Comment: @Legna no entiendo a qué te refieres con *modo consola*. Es para presentar los datos en una aplicación Android.

Comment: Esto.. es interesante... seguro se puede hacer en java (o en c#, o en css, o en en lenguaje de vista que tengamos)... Solo una duda... sabemos de antemano cuantos caracteres entran en el campo? se puede calcular? se puede saber? que pasa si el usuario puso su pantalla en un modo de texto mas grande... se puede calcular? se puede saber?

Comment: @gbianchi no se sabe de antemano el tamaño de la segunda cadena, pero se puede calcular su longitud al momento de obtenerla. El usuario puede de hecho ampliar el tamaño del texto y las dimensiones varían según los múltiples dispositivos Android que hay, resoluciones de pantalla etc. y está también la posibilidad de que el usuario presente los datos en modo vertical o en modo horizontal. Estoy mirando si es posible hacerlo con la clase Span de Android ¿?

Comment: y... si le dejas que lo haga solo el dispositivo? supongo que se puede armar una grilla.. separar esa cadena en dos es facil... y en la grilla, poner solo una fila, con dos columnas, y la primer columna justificarla a un lado y la segunda a otro ;)... hasta podes sacarle los bordes...

Comment: @gbianchi no había pensado en esa posibilidad. Verás, es una gran cantidad de texto que yo presento para la lectura en un solo TextView, tampoco quiero armar un lío para algo que es más que nada estético. O sea, no quiero sobrecargar la App con vistas para lograr algo simple. Para este caso, estaría tirando de dos TextView sólo para un poco de texto y hay varios contenidos que deben presentarse así, por lo que preferiría algún tipo de solución basado en estilos (algo parecido a CSS) donde yo aplique esos estilos a este texto, siguiendo presentando todo ene un solo contenedor (TextView).

Comment: Entonces supongo que para que alguien te ayude, vas a necesitar mostrar un [mcve]... porque asi como esta, por ejemplo, mi idea funciona, pero a vos no te funciona....

Comment: @gbianchi estoy haciendo unas pruebas con SpannableString... ahora edito si no logro hacerlo funcionar.